# Clean solution maintains pssym files from PostSharp

Tags: c#, postsharp

I am using PostSharp in my project. PostSharp creates so called `.pssym` files during build in the bin folder. But when I clean the solution, the pssym files are not removed.

Is there a way to clean these files when I press *Clean Solution*?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with PostSharp 2.1.7.28

Comment: What PostSharp and Visual Studio version do you use? It is cleaned for me in 4.2.11 and 4.1.28.

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Comment: PostSharp 2.1.7.28 is an old version and branch 2.1 is not actively maintained anymore. I would suggest to upgrade to a later version if possible. You can try upgrading the VS extension first, and keep 2.1.7.28 referenced in your project. Normally, all files in the bin/obj folders should be cleaned by the standard MSBuild task. Do you get any warning when trying to clean the solution?